# How to read one file into multiple arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, split

I am currently using the ruby ssh gem where i have three variables HOST, USER, and PASS. I have a file (HOST_USER_PASS.txt) formatted like so:
HOST,USER,PASS
HOST,USER,PASS

I want to read these into an array and then use those variables within the gem. I am currently using split with a while loop but nothing is working so far.

```
file = File.open("HOST_USER_PASS.txt", 'r') 
# Open file"HOST_USER_PASS.txt", read that file
while !file.eof? #run while end of file is not true
      line = file.readline
      fields = line.split(",") #splits line at the comma
ssh gem etc.
end
```

SO the question is, how can i read a file into three separate arrays?

Comment: show us your try

Comment: Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it kinda seems like you're asking the community to do your work for you...

Comment: i have added my code attempt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read text from file into an array in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870588/how-to-read-text-from-file-into-an-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it correctly, your triplets are space separated. Try this one

```
file = File.open("HOST_USER_PASS.txt", 'r') 
while !file.eof?
  line = file.readline
  one, two, three = line.split(" ").map { |fields| fields.split(",") }
  # use one, two and three
  # each of these variable is an array with host, user and password
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am very to ruby as well as computer science in general. Sorry if the question was unclear.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong. This is what i did:                       `HOST = Array.new[0]
USER = Array.new[0]
PASS = Array.new[0]

file = File.open("HOST_USER_PASS.txt", 'r')
line = file.readline
HOST, USER, PASS = line.split(" ").map { |fields| fields.split(",") }`       how do i format this?

Comment: file_array:8: warning: already initialized constant HOST
file_array:2: warning: previous definition of HOST was here
file_array:8: warning: already initialized constant USER
file_array:3: warning: previous definition of USER was here
file_array:8: warning: already initialized constant PASS
file_array:4: warning: previous definition of PASS was here
i get these  errors

Comment: I updated my answer with the rest of your script. you should now use variables `one`, `two` and `three`. have you tried?

Comment: i tried wrong(see jargon above, is there a way to format code in comments?) haha. let me try this now.

Comment: i keep getting an issue: warning: already initialized constant PASS file_array:4                                                                                                                  my array is simply HOST = Array.new(3)

Comment: I' going to talk to my mentor for the array part. Thanks you for all the help i will up vote and mark as correct. As your answer is working, but my logic around it is not. Thanks again for working with me! :)

Comment: don't worry. I'd help you more but I'm not sure I actually got your file structure and everything else about ssh and those variables that I don't see in your code. keep up :)

Comment: Is there a way I could dm you? I have moved what your answer into a separate file. the only change is the definition of the arrays above your code block. All of which have the same formatting. HOST = Array.new(2)

Comment: Leave me some contact

Comment: vi11agio.creeyt@gmail.com